# Bitcoin "scantxoutset" rpc command return response too slow

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development, scantxoutset

For one of our decentralized mobile wallet, We need to fetch balance of imported BTC address quickly.

After lot of research on google then I found Bitcoin deamon rpc command "scantxoutset", which give unspent outputs of imported address.

The only problem with this command is that it takes more than a minute to return the response, which is too slow. User will not wait for 1 minute.

Anyone, could you please suggest me, is there any alternative to fetch the balance of imported BTC address quickly from the BTC node. ( not from any third party api)

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why it takes time. [listunspent](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/listunspent/) can also be used to get balance of imported address. Example: `listunspent 1 9999999 "[\"tb1qyf69xlfvmm6s7a9rtjap2vdnfdmalp6zqutg73\"]"` Also if its slow because of lot of addresses or something else maybe you can manage the UX in a way that user can do something else while this is being done in the background.

Comment: `listunspent` is fast because it queries your own wallet, but it only works for addresses that are yours or otherwise imported (needing a very slow rescan first to find transactions that affect the wallet). `scantxoutset` queries the blockchain database, works for any address, but has to read through the database, so it's faster than rescanning.