# How can I get address's balance that doesn't belong to my Bitcoin core wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have been looking for a way to see the address's balance that doesn't belong to my own Bitcoin core wallet.

I don't like to use an external API, I have this full node and I really wonder if this is possible.

I saw this Pieter Wuille's answer: [How to get an address's balance with the bitcoin client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10090/how-to-get-an-addresss-balance-with-the-bitcoin-client)

But it is an old answer when Bitcoin core even didn't support addresses as watch-only.

What I can understand from his answer is I can't see this information on my Bitcoin core, but right now with Bitcoin core v0.20.1, is that still not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Import addresses in bitcoin core and use [listunspent](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/listunspent/) or [scantxoutset](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/blockchain/scantxoutset/) (`scantxoutset` doesn't require importing addresses as mentioned by sipa in the comments)

OR

2. Setup open source block explorers that use bitcoin core and use their API to get the required results:

https://github.com/dgarage/NBXplorer

https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora

Comment: to add to 1. he can use this command: https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/rpc/wallet/importaddress/

Comment: scantxoutset doesn't require importing

Comment: Yes just realized it won't require addresses to be imported: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/12196. I never used it and assumed it will work similar to `listunspent` because of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99278/bitcoin-scantxoutset-rpc-command-return-response-too-slow

Comment: I wouldn't like to add the address as watch-only because I would like to check many addresses's balance. Could you provide an example using `scantxoutset` with an address as a parameter? I saw the documentation but I didn't see how I can add an address in the scan objects.

Comment: `scantxoutset start "[\"addr(tb1qfg7456fh3u4wkff42zpznhjs3w5hcn469p3ymy)\"]"`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/bNsoGER.png

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I was looking for!