# Get any bitcoin wallet balance without other api

Tags: balance

I have installed bitcoind. Now I'd like get any address balance, number of ingoing transactions and amount of ingoing BTC. What is the best to do it? I didn't found way to do it using RPC bitcoin api.

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/99288/

Comment: It's note my question. Thank you for answering